# react-native build failing with error code 65 and ___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, react-native, xcodebuild

I am trying to build a React Native app. I have already worked with other react native projects previously and haven't faced any issues. This time, I am not able to run the app.

I created a new react-native project with:

```
npx react-native init demoproject
```

and ran it with:

```
cd demoproject
npx react-native start
npx react-native run-ios
```

In the terminal, I got this error:

> error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening demoproject.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

When I tried running it with Xcode, I got this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow", referenced from:
  _RAND_poll in libcrypto.a(rand_unix.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried these steps without any success.

```
react-native start --reset-cache
rm -rf node_modules/
rm -rf package-lock.json 
cd ios
pod deintegrate
cd ..
rm -rf ios/Podfile.lock 
npm install
npm audit fix
react-native link
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
react-native run-ios
```

Environments:

```
Xcode: 11.2 (11B52)
OS: mac OS Catalina 10.15.1
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.62.2
```

I have a few other react-native projects that I tried and they run successfully. They also run on the same react-native version(0.62.2)

Is there anyway to solve the issue? Will updating Xcode to another version like 11.4 or 11.6 solve the problem?

Answer (score 9):

You have to remove Flipper Pod from file goto
Your Project Folder->ios->Podfile and comment Flipper from that file as below

```
 #use_flipper!
 #post_install do |installer|
   #flipper_post_install(installer)
 #end
```

Now from ios folder enter below command in terminal

```
 pod install
```

It will fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks, @Chavda this is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

A temporarily workaround:

1. Comment all flipper functions in podfile;
2. Remove flipperInit in appDelegate.m;
3. Run pod install inside ios folder;
4. Clean project;
5. Run project again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with

1.Comment all the below mentioned 4 flipper function lines in Podfile

**use_flipper!**

**post_install do |installer|**

**flipper_post_install(installer)**

**end**

2.run `pod install`

3.run the project.

This resolved my issue.